# iOS classes in application as data transfer objects

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, dto

I am currently working on a project which enables many features.

One of them is the registration of a user. I do have a view controller as well as a view for handling the user input. I further did implement a UserService starting an uploader to upload the user data and notifying the view controller if if the upload succeeds/fails and so on.

Now, I will not save the data to coredata (just parts of them) and was wondering about the best approach to send the data throughout my application from the view controller to my uploaders.

I know that the easy approach will be something like:

```
- (void) startUserRegistrationEmail:(NSString *) aEmail
                          firstname:(NSString *) aFirstname
                               name:(NSString *) aName
                          birthdate:(NSDate *) aBirthdate
                        citizenship:(NSString *) aCitizenship
                             street:(NSString *) aStreet
                       streetnumber:(NSString *) aStreetNumber
                           postcode:(NSString *) aPostcode
                            address:(NSString *) aAddres;
```

The advantage is that my service and uploader is not depending on any model which might increase reusability.

But there are several disadvantages in my opinion. 
I have to validate the input fields within the view controller. If I had a model object, I could easily stuff all inputs into this object, call is valid and in case it fails, form a proper error which will be displayed to the user.

Further my methods in the service and the uploader will shrink to

```
- (void) startCustomerRequestQueryEmail:(AMRegistration *) aRegistration
```

Due to the fact, that the data of the AMRegistration class will not be saved within coredate, I would not implement it as a managedObject, but a custom class.

After the upload completes, I might look at the reference and save the data I need to my managed objects. (Which is another advantage due to the fact that I do not need to hold references on 9 string but just on one AMRegistration object).

I would like to know how you are handling those issues? Are u using those "helper objects" more often or do you avoid to use them?

Comment: Of course it's good idea to wrap it into one "unit". In C it was structures, but in Objective C you can use class, which can also handle memory management of your data...